# Is it possible to see the returned value of a map function before its execution is complete?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if its possible to see an element in the new array within the map function before it completes execution of the map. i.e. `new_arr[index-1]`

```
var new_arr = [10,20,30].map(function (item, index, arr) {
  console.log(new_arr[index-1]);
  return item + 1;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: no you do not have access to the temporary result array of map.

Comment: sorry misreading your question.

Comment: `new_arr` is not completely initialized while you debugging it. So, the answer is: **NO**

Comment: You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Guess ill just find another way to achieve this.